# Create a dataframe using tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have three tuples :

```
x = (1,2,3)
y = (4,5,6)
z = (7,8,9)
```

I want to create a DataFrame which has a column containing the variable name of the set and another column with the values.

Example output:

```
x 1
x 2
x 3
y 4
...
..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['x']*len(x) + ['y']*len(y) + ['z']*len(z), 'val':x+y+z})
```

Answer (score 0):

Note you have tuples, not set. With sets, your result will not be well-defined as sets are unordered. You can use `numpy.repeat` with `itertools.chain`.

This solution assumes you have a starting dictionary with an arbitrary number of items. A dictionary is recommended for a variable number of variables.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

x = (1,2,3)
y = (4,5,6)
z = (7,8,9)

d = {'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z}

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': np.repeat(list(d), list(map(len, d.values()))),
                   'value': list(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))})

print(df)

  key  value
0   x      1
1   x      2
2   x      3
3   y      4
4   y      5
5   y      6
6   z      7
7   z      8
8   z      9
```